# Подключеный локальный диск не читается

Tags: php

У меня такая проблема! подключил сетевой (локальный диск). Хочу просканировать его с помощьяю php, но не получается. В чем может быть проблема? Использую метод `scandir()`.

Comment: А ОС его открывает?

Comment: Да! Доступ только на чтение.

Comment: PHP и сетевой диск??? Такое возможно? А главное, зачем?

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Сразу минус, нормально ответить нельзя?

Comment: Я отвечу - какой практический смысл вашего ответа?<br>
Лично мне ваше мнение по этому вопросу не интересно, не знаете ответа - промолчите...<br><br>
Ненравится вопрос? <br>Минусуйте, комментируйте но зачем отвечать "абыб ответить?"

Comment: Ребят! на сетевом диске мне нужны файлы которые после обработки поместятся в базу! можно конечно через ftp! но у меня большая организация и безопастность не разрешает! т.к компьютер с интернетом!

Comment: Какая версия PHP?

Может проблема в самой функции ScanDir?!? Как вариант попробуйте написать свою функцию сканирования, используя opendir и рекурсию. Примеры такой функции можно найти в интернете. 

Еще один вариант - Appache стартует при загрузке компьютера автоматически, а сетевые диски монтируются после того, как пользователь вошел в систему. Поэтому при автоматическом старте даже из под учетной записи администратора он не видит сетевых дисков. Как вариант можно дождаться загрузки компьютера и вручную произвести старт службы Appache, прописанную под Вашей учетной записью (не SYSTEM).

Comment: PHP Version 5.2.8

Comment: Попробуйте еще так, помимо вышеуказанного: Локальные параметры безопасности - Локальные политики - Назначение прав пользователя - Работа в режиме ОС- добавьте нужную учетную запись

Comment: ikot ты молодец просто умный человек честно спосибо большое всё работает! 2 недели парился!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте запустить службу Appache под другой учетной записью (например, администратора. по умолчанию Appache использует SYSTEM).
Возможно также придется установить локальную политику безопасности «Сетевой доступ: запретить анонимный доступ к именованным каналам и общим ресурсам» в отключено.

**Но Вы подвергаете свой компьютер дополнительным угрозам.**

Comment: я перепробовал ни чего с доступ и политикой не получается(